# IOS - How to create a modal user/password outside the UIApplication?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, dylib

I am not sure this can be done at all...

Background: I am constructing an in-house application which means it does not get into appstore so i am not limited by the appstore guidelines.

I have a dylib which loads before the main application. It is a kind of augmenting library for applications. I am using the constructor `__attribute__` to load my stuff. In there i would like to put an alertview or any kind of popup which will receive a user/password question. If the password is correct than the user is allowed to continue into the original application.

Since this is in the dylib i do not yet have a UIApplication and i do not want to interfere in the original application or sources.

Suggestions, tips are welcome...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i've done very similar thing in my application:

0) Intercept `applicationDidFinishLaunching` message, add your own code, run original implementation.

1) Make opaque fullscrean UIWindow (for example, black).

2) Set its `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelAlert + 1` So it hides every other window in app.

3) Add fields for user and password to this UIWindow.

Comment: I like this one.
I already intercepted applicationDidFinishLaunching but did not use the windowLevel. I did manage to hide the previous window by taking out its rootViewController (and later giving it back). That seemed too much to me. I'll try it your way...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't show a UIAlertView without having initialized the UIApplication and UIWindow instance.

Only the iOS itself can show alerts outside the application, for example when it asks for permissions or in case of iTunes or game center login ...

As a workaround you can:

- make a login view inside the application
- create a web application for the login process. The web app could launch the native app with a custom URL scheme and pass parameters like 'user' and 'password' to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a View for the Login then if you pass the login you can go on using the app otherwise you just make the app shut itself.

Comment: But in the dylib the application is yet non existant so how will i popup such a view?
Alternatively i swizzled the application delegate but i am not sure how to stop the windows of the original application from being activated and shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a thread when loading your dylib and make it listen for your `UIApplication` to become available, then display the alert on the main thread.

Comment: I can already swizzle the application delegate to do that, the problem is that the views of the original application is being drawn on the screen due to the asynchronous nature of the application.

Comment: What are you swizzling? have you tried swizzling your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`?

Comment: Yes, i did. I successfully say i did :)